# Backbone view does not update when model in collection is saved or deleted

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've scoured StackOverflow and the rest of the interwebz trying to find a solution to this with no success. I'm learning Backbone and can't seem to crack this. It works perfectly on RESTful CRUD operations, it's just that when the collection is updated (for example, if someone does a POST request to add a record to the database), nothing changes on the page.

To my understanding, on a model.save success callback, I don't need to explicitly declare anything because, according to Backbone's docs, it automatically updates the collection in which the models live. Why then is nothing changing on the displayed page when I add/edit/delete? GAH! Here's the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/template" id="search_template">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search_input" />
        <input type="text" id="number" />
        <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" id="edit_button" value="Edit" />
        <input type="button" id="delete_button" value="Delete" />
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="row_template">
        <tr>
            <td><%= id %></td>
            <td><%= name %></td>
            <td><%= job %></td>
        </tr>
    </script>
    <div id="view">

    </div>
    <table id="rows">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Jobs</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="lmao">

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var lel = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: 'lol.php' });
        //var x = new lel;
        //var lee = Backbone.Mode.extend();

        var rows = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: lel, url: 'lol.php' }); 

        dice = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            initialize: function(){ 
                this.render(); 
            },
            render: function(a){
               this.$el.html($('#search_template').html());
            }, 
            events: {
                'click input[value="Add"]': 'hay',
                'click #search_input': 'gaz',
                'click #edit_button': 'edit',
                'click #delete_button': 'del'
            },
            gaz: function(){ $('#search_input').val('') },
            hay: function(){ 
                var self = this;
                var x = new lel;
                x.save({ name: $('#search_input').val(), id: null }); 
            },
            edit: function(){
                var x = new lel;
                x.save({ name: $('#search_input').val(), id: $('#number').val() }, { success: function(r){ alert(r.toJSON()); } }); 
            },
            del: function(){
                var x = new lel({ id: $('#number').val() });
                x.destroy({ success: function(r){ console.log(r.toJSON()); } }); 
            }
        });

        var lmf = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll(this, "render"); 
                this.collection = new rows();
                this.collection.on("change:all", function(){ alert('changed'); }, this);
                this.collection.fetch({ success: this.render }); 
                console.log(this.collection);
                console.log(this.model);
            },
            render: function(){
                var self = this;
                _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
                    //console.log('row '+item);
                    var dict = item.toJSON();
                    var template = _.template($('#row_template').html())
                    var html = template(dict);
                    self.$el.append(html);
                });
            },
            addAll: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.$el.append('fafa');
                //this.$el.html(this.model.get('id'));
            }
        });

        //this.$el.html(self.collection.length);
        var throz = new dice({ el: $('#view') });
        var v = new lmf({ el: $('#lmao') });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The server responds (when .fetch() is called) with a standard JSON array:

```
[{"id":"60","name":"r","job":""},{"id":"55","name":"r","job":""},{"id":"54","name":"s","job":""},{"id":"53","name":"r","job":""},{"id":"56","name":"ee","job":""},{"id":"57","name":"r","job":""},{"id":"58","name":"ffff","job":""},{"id":"59","name":"rrrrrr","job":""}]
```

Please help! This is so frustrating!

Comment: The only event binding on the collection is `this.collection.on("change:all", ...)` and that is listening for the `all` attribute to change. You need to listen for other events (http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). And switch to `listenTo` and get rid of all that old `var self = this` (there are almost always better ways these days) stuff while you're at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what `@mu is too short` mentioned in the comments, your view is not listening for the right event on your `collection`. You should be listening for the `add` or `remove` events that get fired. In other words set up the listeners:

```
this.listen to(this.collection, "add", this.render);
this.listen to(this.collection, "add", this.render);
```

in your view. If you want to detect a change in a `model`, then in your `childView` you'll have to set up a listener that waits for the `model`to change, i.e.,

```
this.listen to(this.model, "change", this.render);
```

Here you only need to `render` the `childView` the `model` is associated with and not the whole collection. If you're looking for a specific attribute to change listen for `"change:attr"` where `attr` is the name of the attribute you want to listen for.